# Regex - isolating string from larger word

Tags: sql, regex, posix, db2-400

The following regex within DB2 SQL works pretty well to get extra elements out of an address (i.e. not the street name or number). Limiting myself to two cases (UNIT or GATE) to keep my example simple, where HAD1 is the field containing the first line of a street address:

```
select HAD1,                                        
 regexp_substr(HAD1,'(UNITS?|GATES?)\s[0-9A-Z]{1,}')
from ECH                                            
where regexp_like(HAD1,'(UNIT|GATE)')               
  and length(trim(HAD1)) > 12
```

I get this:

```
Ship To                                             REGEXP_SUBSTR
Address                                                          
Line 1                                                           
UNIT 4, 117 MONTGOMORIE RD                          UNIT 4       
END OF WAINUI RD, HIGHGATE                          -            
UNIT 3, 37 TE ROTO DRIVE                            UNIT 3       
GATE 6 52 MAHIA ROAD                                GATE 6       
UNIT B 11 LANGSTONE LANE                            UNIT B       
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2                          GATE 2       
GOODS: PLACEMAKERS - WESTGATE                       -            
UNIT 3, 37 TE ROTO DRIVE                            UNIT 3       
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2                          GATE 2       
SH 8A TARRAS-LUGGATE HIGHWAY                        GATE HIGHWAY
```

Which is very encouraging. It correctly didn't pick up HIGHGATE or WESTGATE because they weren't followed by a space then something else.

But it did pick up LUGGATE (last line), which I don't want. So, I'd like to be able to include that my text strings are not preceded by any character.

As you may guess I'm an absolute beginner with regex, so thank you for your patience.

**Edit**
Now I have my most excellent regex like so:

```
\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}
```

Using it over a larger data set I notice the occasional unwanted match where, for instance, GATE is followed by an ordinary English word:

```
THE THIRD GATE ON THE LEFT  =  GATE ON
```

The gates, levels, doors and units that I'm looking for will always be followed by one of the following: (a) A number of up to 6 digits  (b) One letter  (c) A number and one letter, possibly with a dash

```
Examples:
UNIT 7A  
GATE 6
GATE 31113
UNIT B
LEVEL B2
LEVEL 2B 
UNIT D06
```

So, my follow up question is, can I limit the number of letters in second part of the expression to 0 or 1, but allow up to six digits.

I've played around with the numbers in curly brackets but they seem to affect only how many characters are returned rather than how many characters must be present.

Comment: you can use `non word character class or space as per your need` i.e `\s(UNITS?|GATES?)\s[0-9A-Z]{1,}`

Comment: Thank you, but that seems to require a space before, which won't be the case if, e.g. "UNIT" is at the start of the line. I get fewer (correct) values extracted with the \s at the beginning.

Comment: check this out [demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9gifR/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I've been kicked off the machine I need to test it on (maintenance outage), but I'll give it a go in about 8-10 hours.

Comment: I think it'll work though, because the IBM manual says: 
**(?<= ... )  Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern matches text preceding the current input position [yada, yada].** 
So it seems to have that feature.

Comment: Try `\b(UNIT|GATE)S?\s+[\dA-Z]`. 
Check it: https://regex101.com/r/8bmv2O/1.

Comment: Thank you to both - both options work beautifully and the first, although longer, has introduced a new concept to me and helped me along the path.